# How to style the image dimensions displayed in the bubble with react native gifted chat?

Tags: css, react-native, image, react-native-gifted-chat

I am using a react-native-gifted-chat and react-native-image-picker and I am trying to style the image that is picked using image picker and appended to gifted chat bubble.
When the image is displayed with the text , if the text is too long it expands the bubble but the image stays the same width and height. How can I make the image to display along with the text like on WhatsApp?

[See WhatsApp example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1131X.jpg)

[See react native gifted chat example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXFm8.png)

Bellow is the render bubble method I use for styling the chat bubble:

```
  const renderBubble = (props) => {
return (
  <Bubble
    {...props}
    // renderMessageText={message.data.text}
    textStyle={{
      left: {
        color: '#757575',

      },
      right: {
        color: palette.white,
      }
    }}
    timeTextStyle={{
      left: {
        color: '#BDBDBD'
      },
      right: {
        color: 'white'
      }
    }}
    wrapperStyle={{
      left: {
        borderBottomLeftRadius: 0,
        padding: 10,
        paddingLeft: 0,
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        marginLeft: -5

      },
      right: {
        backgroundColor: '#FF7074',
        borderBottomRightRadius: 0,
        padding: 4,
        // width: '46%'
      }
    }}
  />
);
```

};

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue by using renderMessageImage prop by react native gifted chat package.

```
const renderMessageImage =(props) => {
return (
  <MessageImage
    {...props}
    imageStyle={{
      width: '98%',
      height: Dimensions.get('window').width,
      resizeMode: 'cover'
    }}
  />
)
```

}